# Asp.net mvc 3 - get the parameter by name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

There is an url

```
http://mysite.com/en-us/articles/browse/en-us/12/byCategory
```

It's known that one of these parameters named `culture`. Of course I can call `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["culture"]` to get the **value** of the `culture`, but it doesn't say me which `en-us` parameter (first or second) named `culture`.

My task is recognize which of parameters named `culture`, replace it with specified value and return the new url. How to do it?

Comment: There's no way we can know that; you need to know your own routing tables to figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can't have two segment parameters with the same name

So if you say `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["culture"]` you will get the correct culture value that is related to a *specific* segment either the first or the second one, depending on your route URL definition which may look like:

```
{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{lang}/{id}/{filter}
```

As you can see there's only one segment parameter called `culture`.

> **Note**: upper route URL definition may not be like yours but it shows an example that could work with your request URL.

### Get current route's URL definition

But otherwise you could get the currently executing route URL definition to locate the correct segment by:

```
((Route)ViewContext.RouteData.Route).Url
```

Casting `RouteBase` to `Route` would probably work in 99% of cases because using custom route classes isn't that common, but even though custom classes are more likely to inherit from `Route` than `RouteBase`.

Parsing this URL definition may be a more challenging task depending on the complexity of your route definitions. But you could more or less successfully match any URL definition against request URL segments. And this may be exactly what you're after.

### Let current route do the replacement for you

But instead of parsing route's URL and replacing correct segment, you could let route itself do it for you simply by:

```
((Route)ViewContext.RouteData.Route)
    .GetVirtualPath(
        ViewContext.RequestContext,
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { culture = "en-GB" }))
    .VirtualPath
```

Comment: He didn't say that he has two segments with the same name. I think in his example he meant that the `id` segment (or some other) could equal to `en-us`. That's why he put `en-us` at two different portions of the url: in order to demonstrate that a string.Replace wouldn't work and in addition to replacing the real culture segment it could replace other segments that have the same value.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I didn't understand it that way, but you mas be correct. So I edited my answer that may be helpful.

Comment: I've already resolved that issue, but your answer is very helpful.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, <<It's known that one(!) of these parameters named culture>>